# How to Check if Session is set in Laravel 5.7

Tags: session, laravel-5

```
<?php

$request = request();
// if (empty($request)) return false; .// That does not work
$loggedUserAccessGroups = $request->session()->get('loggedUserAccessGroups');
$logged_user_ip = $request->session()->get('logged_user_ip');
```

In my Laravel 5.7 application, I want to check if the user has the right access level in the session. It works ok but I made automatic tests and got the error:

> local.ERROR: Session store not set on request.

I added checks to see if the session is set and it fails to return false.

Which is the correct way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also use the global session PHP function to retrieve and store data in the session as outlined here:

```
// Retrieve a piece of data from the session with the global session helper...
$loggedUserAccessGroups = session('loggedUserAccessGroups');
$logged_user_ip = session('logged_user_ip');

// Store a piece of data in the session...
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

For more information look at the [section of The Global Session Helper in the official documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#using-the-session)